# VMs in Azure Availability Set showing same Fault Domain and Update Domain

Tags: azure

I created just 2 VMs in the same Resource Group and Availability Set using the Azure portal. However, when I look at the availability set, I see that both the VMs are in the same FD and UD.

I thought that the Azure system selects the FD and UD for VMs in the same Availability Set. So why is it setting the same FD and UD.

Do I need to select different Locations to ensure that the VMs fall in different FD/UD? I had selected the same location in the Basic Settings dialog when creating the VMs.

Thanks

Comment: What you thought is what should happen! Machines in the same AV should be in a different FD/UD - this might need an Azure Support call. How did you deploy them?

Comment: I used the new portal to create everything. If what I am thinking is correct, then I'll delete the VM and recreate it. Hope it works this time. Otherwise, I guess I'll need to make that support request as suggested by you. Thanks.

Comment: You could perhaps try deploying via Powershell, I can't imagine it will be any different! but it might be useful to share with either us and / or Azure support.

Comment: Just created a new VM in another Availability set. This worked as it should. So maybe there is some problem with the initial Availability set. Like I said earlier, I'll try creating another VM in the earlier Availability set and see if it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the VMs and recreated them. Once they were both running, the VMs were showing in different UD, FD